# Update array value in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have this piece of code :

```
$start = ['23','', 'what'];
foreach($start as $i){
  if($i ==''){
    $i = 'satisfaction';
  }
}
print_r($start);
```

The output is :

```
Array
(
[0] => 23
[1] => 
[2] => what
)
```

Why did index [1] not get replaced with 'satisfaction'. In other words : I don't want to create a new array, but change the index of an existing array. Actually, what I'm trying to achieve is to do `intval()` on those indexes that are not empty (since intval on an empty index returns 0, which is not what I want).

Comment: print_r($i); and check the result

Comment: try $start[$i] = 'satisfaction';

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede `$value` with `&`. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

So in your case, you should add `&`:

```
$start = ['23','', 'what'];
foreach($start as &$i){
               // ^ reference
    if($i === ''){
        $i = 'satisfaction';
    }
}
```

Sidenote: If your intent is to change those numeric values into data type integer, you can use (as you stated) `intval` or a simple type cast.

```
$start = ['23','', 'what'];
foreach($start as &$i){
    if(is_numeric($i)){
        $i = (int) $i;
    }
}

var_dump($start);
```

Comment: OP's jumped on the *runaway train* bound for Cleveland.

Comment: looks it to be. oh well, I guess maybe the E-train will take them back ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because foreach(...) acts "a bit" as a read-only iterator. If you want to modify elements, you'll have to access by reference.

example :

```
foreach ($start as &$i) {

}
```

For more info, see doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are just setting the variable `$i`, which is just a temporary variable for the loop. Instead, keep the array key in the loop and use that to set the value in the array:

```
$start = ['23','', 'what'];
foreach($start as $k=>$i){
  if($i ==''){
     $start[$k] = 'satisfaction';
  }
}
```

Comment: This's much better than using a reference.